# Select different elements from parent by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am learning about developing, and i have a question with jQuery. I have some code here:

```
<div id="name_1">
  <p class="my_p">I need this value too</p>
  <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of <p> tag</a>
</div>
```

Yes, my question is in my link: How can i get value of `<p>` tag only in it's parent after i clicked the link? I tryed some code like this, but they were not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_link').click(function(){
        var get_value = $('.my_p').parent().html(); //Returned all html codes in <div>
        var get_value = $('.my_p').parent().text(); //Returned all texts in <div>
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find() method to get the class text .my_p from parent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.my_link').click(function(){
    var get_value = $(this).parent().find('.my_p').text(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, Simple and effective. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer. It has a pretty obvious error.

Comment: Can You tell me what is that pretty obvious error ?

Comment: Yes hehehehe I got it I forgot to use the single quotes

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `prev()` jquery function to achieve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_link').click(function(){
        var get_value = $(this).prev('p').html();
        console.log(get_value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name_1">
    <p class="my_p">I need this value too</p>
    <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of <p> tag</a>
</div>
```

Comment: My codes just is an example how to get diffirent elments of their parents. The 'prev' is not really good for me. In reality, my plugin is more complex.

Comment: sory, but i use local language in my lugin, and many php functions. It will be bad look when i copy them in here. I had an answer, thanks a bout your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the `.my_p` selector will return *all* the elements with that class. To find the one related to the clicked `.my_link` you need to use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event, along with jQuery's DOM traversal methods.

Also note that you need to use HTML entities for the `<p>` in the text of the `a` element, otherwise it is interpreted as HTML, and will break the layout. Try this:

```js
$('.my_link').click(function() {
  var get_value = $(this).closest('div').find('.my_p').text();
  console.log(get_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name_1">
  <p class="my_p">I need this value too #1</p>
  <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of &lt;p&gt; tag</a>
</div>
<div id="name_2">
  <p class="my_p">I need this value too #2</p>
  <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of &lt;p&gt; tag</a>
</div>
<div id="name_3">
  <p class="my_p">I need this value too #3</p>
  <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of &lt;p&gt; tag</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.my_link').click(function(){
    var p_text = $(this).parent().find('.my_p').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the element inside the parent tag. Or use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method since its sibling just before the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_link').click(function() {
  
    // get parent and get first p tag inside
    var get_value = $(this).parent().find('.my_p').text();
    
    // or using prev
    var get_value1 = $(this).prev('.my_p').text();
    
    console.log(get_value, get_value1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name_1">
  <p class="my_p">I need this value too</p>
  <a href="#" class="my_link">Click me for get value of &lt;p&gt; tag</a>
</div>
```